# Sonar lint plugin installation failed

Tags: spring-tool-suite, sonarlint-eclipse

I'm using STS 4.12.0.RELEASE and try to install sonar lint 6.1 plugin from eclipse market place. But received java.lang.IllegalStateException: operation plan must be resolved as the attached image.

Is there any alternative way to install the sonar lint plugin?[image]

[image]

Added additional image about failure message [image]

Answer (score 0):

The installation of the SonarLint plugin from the marketplace works for a fresh STS 4.12.0 distribution in general, so this might be a network glitch, stale cached data from the update site, or something in this area.

I would recommend to go to the `Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites` and remove (not just disable) the update site for SonarLint in there, restart, and try again.

Comment: The following solution not available: SonarLint 6.1 
Proceed with installation anyways?

This is the message receiving after changes in preferences

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. What happens if you use a fresh STS 4.12.0.RELEASE install on an empty workspace, go to the Marketplace, and try SonarLint install?

Comment: I added a additional image about the issue in the initial question. Can you please check Martin Lippert

Comment: Can you confirm that you are running a fresh STS 4.12.0.RELEASE installation using a fresh and empty workspace?

Comment: Martin, I used sonarlint latest (6.1.0) zip from this path https://binaries.sonarsource.com/SonarLint-for-Eclipse/releases/     and added sonar lint using Install New Software from STS. and issue solved.

I Currently use Version: 4.12.0.RELEASE